# How to create toggle buttons in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I need to create a group of 5 buttons. Only one can be pressed, like Radio Button, but I do not want to show the circle. I would like to use the button look.

Somebody do know which is the best way to do it?

I have found for WPF:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
```

but it does not work for Windows 8.

Thank you

Comment: You can create a custom control based on the RadioButton and change its look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a group of actual buttons with an action assigned to the click event of each, or are you just trying to remove the circle form a RadioButton type control?

Please note that the user will likely expect a RadioButton control to look and feel like a RadioButton.  Changing this just for the sake of it may not be a good idea, but if you want to go ahead with it you could try one of the following options.

1) Edit the template for a radiobutton control to hide the selcetion circle.  (I don't know if that's even possible in all honesty, but in theory, it should be)
*or*
2) Emulate the behaviour with a ListView with SelctionMode set to "Single"

Things get a little more complicated if you want to handle  click events on each "button", but it is not impossible.  In your ItemTemplate, add a button (presumable with a style  of "TextButtonStyle") and set the event handler of the Click event to check which button was pressed and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a control called [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx), why don't you use that?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is an option but ToogleButton has nothing about groups. I mean if you press a button, the last pressed button needs to be released. I have several ways, but none is a direct way. I was inquiring if there is a short or optimal way to get this behavior.